# Make Disabled Radiobuttons not greyed out (Behave as read-only)

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, dynamics-crm

I have a request from users to modify Microsoft CRM to make it's read-only fields not greyed out, but still read only.  By inspecting the DOM I've learned that the radio controls are set as disabled.  To accomplish this request I have no ability to change how the application is generating the html.  However, I do have the ability to run a javascript function on the forms onload event.  I have tried a few different approaches, most recently I tried using jQuery to remove the disabled attribute and attach event handlers to the radio's to change their values back if a user tries to change them.

Using this approach I learned that the change event fires on the control the user clicks, but does not fire on the radio button that was unselected by the selection of another radio button in the same group.

To get arround this I tried writing a custom property to all the radio controls that record whether it was checked when the page was loaded, and then an event handler that resets the checked property on every radio button with a custom attribute to it's original value whenever any radio button's change event fires.  This method is not working for me either however.  I'm going to include a sample application to show my approach.  I would appreciate help fixing my code, or help meeting these needs using a different approach.

I wanted to restate the requirements one more time for any solution I come up with.

1. Solution only needs to be written to IE.
2. I have no control over the generated HTML, only the ability to write javascript.
3. Fields that are set as disabled need to be rendered in black, not greyed out.
4. Users must not be able to change the values of these fields.

   ```
   <script src="js/jquery.1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           //Set custom attribute for disabled checked radio's
           $('input:radio:disabled:checked').attr('custom:bmiChecked', "true");
           //set custom attribute for disabled unchecked radio's
           $('input:radio:disabled:not(:checked)').attr('custom:bmiChecked', "false");
           //select disabled radio's and then filter to radio's that have the custom attribute set
           $('input:radio:disabled').filter(function () {
               return $(this).attr('custom:bmiChecked');
           }).each(function () {
               //attach a click event handler
               $(this).click(function () {
                   //In the event handler select all radio's that have the bmiChecked attribute
                   $('input:radio').filter(function () {
                       return $(this).attr('custom:bmiChecked');
                   }).each(function () {
                       //For each of these radio's set their checked property to the original value from the page load.
                       if ($(this).attr('custom:bmiChecked') == "true") {
                           $(this).attr('checked', "").css({ 'border': '5px solid green' });
                       }
                       else {
                           $(this).attr('checked', "checked").css({ 'border': '5px solid red' });
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
           //remove all the disabled properties from radiobutton's
           $('input:radio:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
       });
   </script>


   <input name="rad_new_bitfield2options" tabindex="1090" class="ms-crm-RadioButton" disabled="" id="Radio2" style="margin-left: 0px;" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />

   <input name="rad_new_bitfield2options" tabindex="1090" class="ms-crm-RadioButton" disabled="" id="Radio3" type="radio" value="2"  />
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a really beautiful solution as @cdeszaq pointed out.
But all you need to do is "recheck" the originally checked button. 
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxFMu/2/).

Comment: The concern I would have with this is that it still allows users to make changes (or at least interact with the form elements), which is rather confusing from a UI / UX standpoint. Otherwise, this is a good workaround :)

Comment: By "interact", I mean the elements can be selected, have mouseovers, etc. (eg. they _look_ like they can be interacted with)

Comment: I totally agree with you (from an HCI point of view). I guess the OP clients wants the form to look like it is active... I had to do something similar sometime ago totally against my will. I was told that a form should look active so that the end user could print it. Go figure... :D.

Comment: I've been there too my friend, I've been there too. But the "printing" reason is one I haven't heard before!

Answer (score 2):

You could have your javascript replace the form fields with other html elements, such as `<p>` elements that contain the same data.

This gets around the need to have the form elements be disabled, and to me at least, makes much more sense. If the users can't change the values anyways, why bother making them form elements?

It's also much more simple that dealing with trying to intercept events and do things to prevent normal behavior.

Comment: I had considered this, but couldn't really come up with another html element that I could dynamically build and would clearly reflect the multiple options available and which one has been selected.

Comment: @Troy - If they can't change the selected option, why does it matter that there are other options? If it does matter, you could turn the options into a table, with one column as `selected` and the other column indicating the particular option. Since this could get rather cluttery, you might want to hide it by default and have a `show more` link that makes it shown / hidden.